# Можно ли как-то указать лишь часть дженериков? И как я могу изменить архитектуру, чтобы решить данную проблему?

Tags: java, generics

Есть следующий интерфейс(Да, я знаю, что его можно заменить `Function<T, V>`, не суть):

```
public interface OutputUI<T, V> {
    void addOutput(T t);
    V getCalculatedOutput();
}
```

Этот интерфейс я использую в другом классе при отправке нового объекта на вывод(предварительно его преобразовывая). В этом другом классе мне совершенно не важен тип `V`:

```
public OutputUI breakDown(){
    out.addOutput("u broke " + name + " with " + rigidity + ", dude");
    return out;
}
```

При получении он тоже не важен.

Первое что приходит на ум - сделать два отдельных интерфейса - `Input<T>` и `Output<V>`.

Но есть ли другие пути? В частности - можно ли указать лишь нужные для работы дженерики?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Часть вы указать не можете. При имплементации интерфейса вам в любом случае надо реализовать все методы. Но если вам не важен тип `V` вы всегда можете передать просто `Object`.

Если вам где-то нужен один метод, где-то несколько можете сделать наследование интерфейсов. Например так

```
public interface OutputUI<T> {
    void addOutput(T t);
}

public interface Calculated <T, V> extends OutputUI<T>  {
    V getCalculatedOutput();
}
```

и тогда можете где нужно использовать `OutputUI` и по необходимости OutputUI_X

или сделать два отдельных интерфейса, если они не связаны

```
public interface OutputUI<T> {
    void addOutput(T t);
}

public interface Calculated <V>{
    V getCalculatedOutput();
}
```

и в реализации использовать их либо по отдельности, либо оба, например

```
public class Calc implements OutputUI<YouType1>, Calculated<YouType2> {

     public void addOutput(YouType1 t1) {
         ...
     }

     public YouType2 getCalculatedOutput{
         ...
     }

}
```

Также можно совершить мощный маневр - можно присвоить экземпляру интерфейса объект класса, даже если мы реализуем его косвенно:

```
interface F<T>{
    void printHi();
}
interface S<Z>{
    void printHello();
}
interface FS<T, Z> extends F<T>, S<Z>{}


class Printer implements FS<String, String>{
    @Override
    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void printHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

`Printer` реализует интерфейс `FS`. Значит он косвенно реализует и интерфейсы `F` и `S`. Значит следующая запись будет верна:

```
F<String> f = new Printer();
S<String> s = new Printer();

f.printHi();
s.printHello();
```

И конечно же эта тоже:

```
FS<String, String> fs = new Printer();

fs.printHi();
fs.printHello();
```

Comment: То есть вы предлагаете просто не использовать дженерики?

Comment: Добавил примеров в ответ. А на счет использования, это надо смотреть по задаче которую вы решаете.

Comment: Спасибо, это очень мощный инструмент. Дополнил ваш ответ.